# Android Emulator would not load from the AVD manager

Tags: android, emulation

Iv been searching on google for this problem but came with no similar problem from anyone else, so there was no answer. I run the emulator from the AVD manager, the loading bar goes almost to the end and then the window disappears and no emulator loads up. Only the AVD manager stares back at me. Anyone knows what could the problem be?

I also have Java ME installed with Java SE, thats for a different platform. Could it be that Java ME is interfering? The emulator works fine on my home computer and there is no Java ME there, but at work it wouldn't load. The whole android SDK folders at work pc and at home pc are both same copy paste from my old home pc that I used to bring to work before.

**This problem wasn't solved and eventually did not occur after a system wipe (required for something else)**

Comment: have you tried making a new virtual device in AVD..and try it

Comment: yes i have and this keeps happening...

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that the screen of the emulator itself just turned off, and you need to turn it on?

try pressing F7 to turn it on.

if that doesn't help , try to create a totally new AVD without setting anything there , and run it.

if nothing helps, remove the folder of the sdk manager and re-install it .

Comment: Yes well I tried everything and nothing happens... All 3 suggestions didn't work

Comment: which android versions of the emulator have you tried to create , and using which CPU architecture? try to disable the GPU feature there . also , try to remove the ".android" folder on your OS . i don't remember where it should be , maybe under "users" for windows OS .